# Adding asterisk to a value in column under certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have sample keyword like below. I want to do something like that.

Workflow:

- If there is no asterisk at the end of the keyword, it will add 2 asterisk at the end.
- If there is one asterisk at the end of the keyword, it will add one asterisk at the end.
- If there is two asterisk at the end of the keyword, it will add one asterisk at the end.

sample:

```
Test Keyword // IT TEST.
Test Keyword1 // IT TEST11
Test Keyword13 // IT TEST131*
Test Keyword13 // IT TEST131**
```

desired output:

```
Test Keyword // IT TEST.**
Test Keyword1 // IT TEST11**
Test Keyword13 // IT TEST131**
Test Keyword13 // IT TEST131***
```

SS:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ? And please add more data to your sample.

Comment: do you need to change existing cells, or is it ok to use Worksheetfunction to calculate output in new cells?

Comment: is it ok to use Worksheetfunction to calculate output in new cells?  ok

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about more than 2 asterisks? I assume that no more is added.
Try a fromula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2)<>"*",A2&"**",IF(RIGHT(A2,3)="***",A2,A2&"*"))
```

[image: asterisk]

Answer (score 0):

This would probably do the job for you assuming the results can come in a different column like your image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell A1, then in B1, type:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1 & "**", "***", "**")
```

This adds two asterisks to everything, which makes 1 > 3 and 2 > 4. Then replaces a sequence of *** with **, taking 4 > 3 and 3 > 2, achieving the desired end result.